# O Provider MSDAORA está retornando "?" ao invés de caracteres especiais

Tags: oracle, codificação-de-caracteres, asp

Estou passando por um problema ao tentar configurar o meu computador para executar a aplicação da mesma maneira que é executado no servidor, os caracteres que são retornados do banco Oracle, aparecem com um sinal de ? no lugar do caracter especial.

As configurações do meu computador são:

> Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits

As configurações do IIS são:

> IIS 7.5

As páginas da aplicação ASP estão definidas com codificação em ANSI e definidas no seu escopo com:

```
Response.CharSet = "ISO-8859-1"
```

O provider utilizado no servidor, e que consequentemente devo replicar no meu computador é o *MSDAORA*.

A versão do oracle é a *11g*.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Poste o valor do `NSL_LANGUAGE`e `NLS_CHARACTERSET` para nós: `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_LANGUAGE');`

Comment: Veja também se clientes externos (sqlplus, sqldeveloper, etc) conseguem retornar o encoding correto (pode ser que o charset esteja correto porém os inserts tenham sido feitos com o encoding errrado).

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE: AMERICAN e NLS_CHARACTERSET: WE8ISO8859P1

Comment: Outra sugestão, o `MSDAORA` é velho e cheio de problemas, talvez valha a pena tentar o `OraOLEDB.Oracle`.

Comment: Pois é meu caro, eu mudei e trouxe sem problemas, o único problema são as chamadas de procedure, alguma coisa é diferente utilizando esse outro provider. Ainda não vi o que é...